# Javascript error on WordPress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, svg

I'm trying to implement [This](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ShapeHoverEffectSVG/index.html) to my web site. I did all things described as [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/07/shape-hover-effect-with-svg/). [This is](http://test.suxiid.com/playtrix/#offers) my site. As I can understand there is a problem with javascript.

This is the js code.

```
function init() {
var speed = 250,
  easing = mina.easeinout;
  [].slice.call ( document.querySelectorAll( '#offers_content > a' ) ).forEach( function( el ) {
  var s = Snap( el.querySelector( 'svg' ) ), path = s.select( 'path' ),
    pathConfig = {
      from : path.attr( 'd' ),
      to : el.getAttribute( 'data-path-to' )
    };

  el.addEventListener( 'mouseenter', function() {
    path.animate( { 'path' : pathConfig.to }, speed, easing );
  } );

  el.addEventListener( 'mouseleave', function() {
    path.animate( { 'path' : pathConfig.from }, speed, easing );
  } );
} ); 
}
init();
})();
```

Please be kind to check my website.You can see html from the site.I already wasted 4 hours for this.Your help will be highly appritiated.

Thanks.

Dhanuka

Comment: You need to be elaborate. What exactly is the problem? I can't see any related issue in console, so it must be something not visually right. What is it?

Comment: Yes. That's the problem.I tried everything I can. I'm sure this is a javascript issue

Comment: @AyeshK  well, I'm trying to change the SVG path on hover.I used above js to do that.But it's not working. That's the problem.

Comment: Seems like querySelectorAll is executed before the DOM is completely loaded, hence no elements are captured.

Comment: @CharithDeSilva well, what should I do ?

Comment: try placing your function inside `$(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ });`

Answer (score 0):

the original site I see the use of  html 5

```
    <section id="grid" class="grid clearfix">
                <a href="#" data-path-hover="m 180,34.57627 -180,0 L 0,0 180,0 z">
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/1.png">
                        <svg viewBox="0 0 180 320" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path d="M180,160C180,160,0,218,0,218C0,218,0,0,0,0C0,0,180,0,180,0C180,0,180,160,180,160"></path><desc>Created with Snap</desc><defs></defs></svg>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2>Crystalline</h2>
                            <p>Soko radicchio bunya nuts gram dulse.</p>
                            <button>View</button>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </a>

</section>
```

I see on your website using < div >

```
      <div id="offers_content" class="grid clearfix">
                <!-- Ajax content here -->
            <a style="" href="http://test.suxiid.com/playtrix/offers/sample-offer-7/" data-path-hover="m 180,34.57627 -180,0 L 0,0 180,0 z" class="offer-link col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 single-offer">
        <figure>
            <img src="http://test.suxiid.com/playtrix/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/offer-img.jpg">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 180 320" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path d="M180,160C180,160,0,218,0,218C0,218,0,0,0,0C0,0,180,0,180,0C180,0,180,160,180,160"></path></svg>
            <figcaption>
                <h2>Sample Offer 7</h2>
                <p>Soko radicchio bunya nuts gram dulse.</p>
                <button>View</button>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
</div>
```